# Specifing file encoding while reading a file with sys.io.File.read in Haxe

Tags: encoding, haxe

I know how to read a file with Haxe by using sys.io.File.read (compare [Reading lines from a file in Haxe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355099/reading-lines-from-a-file-in-haxe) and I also know that the sys module is not available for each target). However how can I tell sys.io.File.read that my text file is encoded via a certain encoding (e.g. UTF-16, UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this at `File`-level, but you can encode / decode the `String` after reading the file. For instance, [`Utf8.encode()`](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/Utf8.html#encode) will convert a ISO-8859-1 string to a UTF-8 string:

```
var isoString = sys.io.File.getContent("iso_file.txt");
var utf8String = haxe.Utf8.encode(isoString);
sys.io.File.saveContent("utf8_file.txt", utf8String);
```

The standard library currently doesn't support UTF-16, but [it's coming in Haxe 4](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3072). In the meantime, you can use libraries such as [unifill](https://github.com/mandel59/unifill) for that.

Btw, if you don't need to read a file line-by-line, [`File.getContent()`](https://api.haxe.org/sys/io/File.html#getContent) is much more convenient than the `File.read()`-approach you linked.

Comment: i18n additions to the standard haxe library here: 
https://github.com/frabbit/haxe-1/tree/unicode_vector/std/haxe/i18n

Compatible with current Haxe dev build, copying over std files prob not work as it has new submodule, so need to Make. 

Usage?
https://github.com/frabbit/haxe-1/blob/unicode_vector/tests/benchs/i18n/Benchmark.hx

Encoding detection?. 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file

but legally encoded checking possible:
https://github.com/frabbit/haxe-1/blob/unicode_vector/std/haxe/i18n/Tools.hx#L222

Comment: Any answer to a question about Haxe from Gama11 is probably the correct one!